# How to add attribute to webgrid's html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I use a webgrid which has a footer in it. When I use footer parameter to add a footer into the output html table of that webgrid it adds my html code inside a td tag of which parent is a tr tag of which parent is a tfoot tag.

```
@grid.Table(tableStyle:"table", 
    columns:grid.Columns(
        ...(six columns)
),
footer: @<text><button type="button">AddUser</button></text>
```

output:

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <button type="button">Add User</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Now I just want a simple thing to do. I only want to add an `align="right"` attribute to the td tag without using any javascript or jquery.

I want to do it with WebGrid logic. Is it possible to add attribute to webgrid's output html using webgrid class?

I think it must be possible. It is just a simple thing. But how?